# Permission denied while mounting windows share wih cifs-utils

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, samba, cifs

I want to access a windows share from my vbox ubuntu machine (I have all proxies set up correctly).

The problem is that I get a permission denied error with no extra reasons when trying to mount via :

```
 mount -t cifs "//server/share" /windowsshare/myshare -o username=<activediruname>,password=<pass>,domain=<ADdomain>,ro
```

I get this error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I have an `$` character inside the password but I don't think that is the problem because I have also tried setting the `PASSWD` env var and removing the `password=` option and still permission denied error.

Any ideas, clues or information about how to debug the information further will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: The `$` might trigger shell's variable expansion -- in both cases (command line option, PASSWD env var). Have you tried to put single quotes around the -o parameter: `... -o 'username=.....'`?

Comment: @DavidPostill: This problem IMHO does not sound corporate network specific, indeed I think it might as well show up in the home network. So, removing both word 'corporate' will make the question perfectly OT?! What do you think?

Comment: @mpy agreed. I edited the question and retracted my vote ;)

Comment: I added single quotes around the options string and sec=krb5,ver=1 , to the command line option and now I get mount error(2): No such file or directory . I don't know if this is before or after the password verification  or after (is it progress?)

Comment: I'd say it is progress as your credentials are accepted by the server now. Regarding the new error, pls check  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154465 -- and try (notice the _s_) `vers=3.0`.

Comment: @mpy I have tried it with vers=3.0 and now  I get mount "error(95): Operation not supported "  with vers=2.1 and 2.0 I get "mount error(5): Input/output error" with vers=1.0 i get "mount error(2): No such file or directory" ... Tried with different other options but I don't know exactly what I am doing.  If you have any other Idea of parameters I will be very grateful . Or a tool (on linux or windows) which which I run to see  what parameters I must pass to cifs utils  or samba client

Comment: Hm, I'm not so deep into different versions if cifs. I wrote an answer for the part with the rejected password (because of the `$` sign in to -- very good you mentioned it!), because I'm pretty sure that's independent from the following issues and is IMHO also _home network_ relevant. May I suggest that with the different new errors you raise a new question, which now may be _coorporate network_ specific, so better suited for  [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)?!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you use an unescape or not-single-quoted dollar sign on the command line, it is subject to *parameter expansion*, i.e. the parameter value is substituted for the parameter name. Let's assume your password is `foo$bar`. I use `echo` to display to actual executed command line:

```
$ echo mount -t cifs ... -o username=user1,password=foo$bar,domain=WIN,ro
mount -t cifs ../../ -o username=user1,password=foo,domain=WIN,ro
$ PASSWD=foo$bar
$ echo $PASSWD
foo
```

You can see the `$bar` part is replaced by nothing, because in this example there is no `bar` parameter set. To prevent this, *use single-quotes* around the `$` or the whole term:

```
$ echo mount -t cifs ... -o 'username=user1,password=foo$bar,domain=WIN,ro'
mount -t cifs ../../ -o username=user1,password=foo$bar,domain=WIN,ro
$ PASSWD='foo$bar'
$ echo $PASSWD
foo$bar
```

So, the reason for the `mount error(13): Permission denied` error is, the server rejects your password, because the shell replaced some parts of it.

Comment: A wierd thing is that after I added the sec=krb5 option and got "mount error(2): No such file or directory" . I changed my password to a wrong one and i still got the same "mount error(2): No such file or directory" error ..

Comment: Have you tested without `sec=kbr5` as in your question? In my test it behaved like one thinks, wrong password (also unquoted $ in it, or intentional wrong) gives _error(13)_, right password (with quoted $) worked.

Comment: I will try some more tomorrow  (I don't have access to the vm now) . I was also thinking .. since I am using virtualbox (with vagrant ) , I could maybe create a local share without authentification of  the network share and pass that to the vim (if it is possible http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html ) . or with guest additions?